# Why is the inline string block in Ruby named "eos"?

Tags: ruby, syntax

Why is the inline string block in Ruby named "eos"?

**Update**

Thank you for denoting the right way. I always thought that "eos" was a reserved word, but it seems that any word may be used:

```
a = <<MYSTRING
line 1
line 2
mystring #the thing is case sensitive
line3
MYSTRING
#The actual end of the string
```

I also discovered that this construction is named [Heredoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document)

This showed me that even the silliest questions can be a learning opportunity.

Comment: This is not correct. Heredoc syntax lets you use any identifier. EOS is just an example of such identifiers

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not about a practical programming problem, as laid out in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 36, accepted):

EOS means end of string. it is displayed at the end of the string.

EOS means more than GFJKDHAGJHFGDJ for example.

But you can use other names, too.

Comment: Amazing! I never knew about that thinking that "eos" is a reserved word. So, this construction is named "Heredoc". I'll remember that.

Comment: `EOS` is not a reserved word. Just a convention